# How to correct issues with CTE in VIEW (MariaDB) where client runs out of memory and row_number does not increment?

Tags: sql, mariadb, common-table-expression

I'm trying to make a view showing a 10 minute moving average where the moving average field returns a NULL value for the first 10 mins of data.

The issues I'm having are:
1. Both the command line and HeidiSQL clients run out of memory (they do not max out my system memory, it must be a software limitation).
2. When I put a LIMIT clause in, the query runs but the values do not increment correctly (ie. row number is always 1, date/time is always the first date/time in the table, etc.).

Table has 604,800 rows and 2 columns.

System specs are:

> Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4
>   Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s) (OC to 4.4 GHz)   Installed Physical
>   Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB

SQL statement is:

```
CREATE VIEW moving_average
AS
WITH cte_rawdata AS
        (SELECT
            date_time, wind_speed
            FROM raw_data),
cte_MA10m AS
        (SELECT
            date_time, wind_speed,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC) AS rn,
            AVG(wind_speed) OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC ROWS BETWEEN 599 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MA10m
            FROM raw_data)
    SELECT
        rn, rd.date_time, rd.wind_speed,
        IF(rn > 599, MA10m, NULL)
        FROM raw_data rd, cte_rawdata, cte_MA10m;
```

Output should look like this (plus row number, not shown):

```
rn datetime windspeed MA10m  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" "5.370000"  
"2" "2018-08-23 00:00:02" "5.36" "5.365000"  
"3" "2018-08-23 00:00:03" "5.37" "5.366667"  
"4" "2018-08-23 00:00:04" "5.34" "5.360000"  
"5" "2018-08-23 00:00:05" "5.01" "5.290000"  
"6" "2018-08-23 00:00:06" "5.00" "5.241667"  
"7" "2018-08-23 00:00:07" "5.35" "5.257143"  
"8" "2018-08-23 00:00:08" "5.73" "5.316250"  
"9" "2018-08-23 00:00:09" "5.37" "5.322222"  
"10" "2018-08-23 00:00:10" "5.35" "5.325000"
```

But instead I get this:

```
rn   datetime          windspeed MA10m  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N  
"1" "2018-08-23 00:00:01" "5.37" \N
```

Note: \N is the correct outcome for this data.

Does anyone know how I can fix these issues?

UPDATE: As per Gordons comment, I updated the last FROM statements to include JOINS, which fixed the datetime and wind speed columns, but still can't get rn to work.

```
    FROM
    raw_data AS rd
    LEFT JOIN cte_rawdata ON rd.date_time = cte_rawdata.date_time
    LEFT JOIN cte_MA10m ON rd.date_time = cte_rawdata.date_time
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Proper `JOIN` conditions will probably solve your problems.

Comment: OK Thanks, updated the original post (this doesn't seem to allow code blocks).  I'm a SQL newb so there will for sure be best practice issues with my code.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN cte_MA10m ON rd.date_time = cte_rawdata.date_time` doesn't look right.

Comment: Neither does joining `raw_data` and `cte_raw_data`.  At a glance I don't see the point of what's for all practical purposes a self join in that. (Or why *any* joins, actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, shouldn't you just be using something like:

```
WITH cte_MA10m AS
    (SELECT
        date_time, wind_speed,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC) AS rn,
        AVG(wind_speed) OVER(ORDER BY date_time ASC ROWS BETWEEN 599 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MA10m
        FROM raw_data)
SELECT
    rn, date_time, wind_speed,
    IF(rn > 599, MA10m, NULL) AS MA10m
    FROM cte_MA10m
    ORDER BY date_time;
```

Your first attempt, with all the pre-SQL92 syntax joins without any `WHERE`, would return `604800^3` rows. The second one with the left joins would produce only `604800^2` rows (Because the second join's `ON` doesn't use the table being joined, every row would be used). But there doesn't seem to be a point to any of that self joining - you can get the calculations you want without any.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly!  I'm so relieved that it is such a simply query after all that.  This query makes much more sense than what I had written.  Thanks!